# ImageMagick on 32-bit Windows - convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format - .svg to .jpg

Tags: svg, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert a .svg file to a .jpg file. I have it working on a 64-bit version of windows 7, but when I installed it on a 32-bit version of Windows Server 2008 and run this command:

```
convert in.svg out.jpg
```

I get this error message:

```
convert.exe no decode delegate for this image format
```

Update #1: I just installed ImageMagick on a new 32-bit Server 2008 VM and the convert works just fine. Not sure what the issue is though on the production computer I need it installed on.

Comment: Did you install the same version on both machines?

Comment: Yes 6.8.9-0-Q16 the only difference is one I installed the x64 and the other I installed the x86

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I'm trying to convert a non-valid svg file. Regular svg files work fine on that server. The svg code that I'm generating is back-slashing all the special characters, but it is only doing it on that server, not any of my other servers. I guess I should have looked at my svg code to start with.